# how to develop Page options in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to WordPress Theme Development. I study many tutorials but i could not achieve desired result. I need WordPress page options inside page menu( from where we add or view all pages or edit/del pages as well). options would look like having textarea, checkboxes,dropdown menus etc. after saving the data entered the content would display on front end. Can anyone help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378062/how-to-develop-wordpress-page-options/22378482

Answer (score 0):

you just create a new page from page option...after that just goto->Appearance->Menu  here you will find your all pages list just check the checkbox which one you want to add in your menu..and then click Add To menu..you page will added and your menu will appear in your website... click to see sample image http://1drv.ms/O9NIDz